# Is it possible to Query existing Test cases into a static suit from a particular test plan in Azure DevOps Test Plans?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to Query existing Test cases into a static suit from a particular test plan. Is it possible to do that?

For Example I have a Test Suit named "Test_Plan_Demo_1" and it consists of some test cases. Now I want to query this tests into a test suit which is there in different test plan "Test_Plan_Demo_2". Is it possible to query in that way?

Comment: Hi! Consider including more data and if possible a minimal reproducible example to get quicker responses. (See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi friend,  does the answer below resolved your question? If yes, appreciate for accepting it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not query that tests, because they do not have any properties to query.  You have to add tag or update test cases name with some keyword. Then you can create a query based test suite.

Additionally, you can import a test suite from another test plan:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Shamrai Aleksander. Import test suites is the most convenient way. You can also export test cases to CSV. [image]
Then, delete the test case ID and import this CSV file to Test_Plan_Demo_2.